# Cannot find DataContractJsonSerializer in VS2010

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a demo Silverlight app and I'd like to do some simple JSON.  I found the  [`System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) class on MSDN, but I can't seem to reference it successfully in Visual Studio 2010.

I have added a reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization`, but I still get a compile error if I have a `DataContractJsonSerializer` (even with a fully qualified class name.  My project is configured to Silverlight 4.  The assembly does have a 2.0 version number when I add the reference, but I can't find a version 4.0 assembly.

Why can't I use this class?

```
Namespace:  System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
Assembly:  System.Runtime.Serialization (in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll file but that is not where you can find the System.Runtime.Serialization.Json namespace. You actually have to reference the **System.ServiceModel.Web.dll** library and that is where the DataContractJsonSerializer class.  On my machine, the DLL was found here: **C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll**